# Azume ML Cannot Find timeSeries function

Tags: r, azure, machine-learning

I am trying to run an `R Script` in `Azure ML Studio`. Unfortunately, I receive the following error:

```
Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:
---------- Start of error message from R ----------
could not find function "timeSeries"
```

It seems strange that `Azure ML cannot` find the `function timeSeries` as the `timeSeries` package is installed by default. Here is the proof, you can see that timeSeries is listed.

[image]

Here is my code and the Azure diagram. The 1st R script was used to write a CSV of the installed packages (1st Picture). The code in the second R script is displayed to the right of the 2nd picture.

[image]
Thanks

Comment: In the script, have you loaded the library.  i.e. `library(timeSeries)` ?

Comment: Shit that was such a stupid mistake! Thanks ahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library needs to be loaded as it is an external library

```
library(timeSeries)
#Map 1-based optional input ports to variables
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) #class: data.frame
HOLD <- maml.mapInputPort(2) #class: data.frame

colnames(HOLD) <- c("Dates", "Val")

Daily.TS <- timeSeries(HOLD$Val, as.Date(HOLD$Dates),
     format="%Y-%m-%d")
```